# How an Observable emits value according to another Observable

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs6

So, let's say, I have an Observable which is created from a huge ordered array with the timestamp value, and I have another Observable that is created from the event(basically is emitting timestamp four times per second).

Here is the question, HOW can I implement so that with second Observable emits values, first Observable emits all value until reach a value that greater than second Observable's emitted value, then waiting for second Observable keep emitting

Keep it short is one Observable keeping emit until it's greater than another Observable's emitted value.

```
e.g. : 
  Observable A [1,1.1,1.5,1.7,2,5,7]
  Observable B [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
B emit 1 -> A emit 1, wait
B emit 2 -> A emit 1.1 1.5 1.7 2 wait
B emit 3........
B emit 7 -> A emit 7
B emit 8 -> A over
```

plus: B is seekable

```
e.g. : 
  Observable A [1,1.1,1.5,1.7,2,5,7]
  Observable B [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
B emit 1 -> A emit 1, wait
B emit 2 -> A emit 1.1 1.5 1.7 2 wait
B emit 3........
suddenly B seek to 2
B emit 2 -> A emit the one in A array which closest to 2
then keep moving
B emit 7 -> A emit 7
B emit 8 -> A over
```

Comment: I would ask if RxJS is really a good fit for what you want to do here. RxJS is made for streaming, there isn't really a concept of "seeking" since streams are supposed to be push based. I would suggest you have a look at the sister project IxJS which might be better suited to your problem.

Comment: @paulpdaniels thank you for your advice, I have already resolved by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this by myself

```
const time$ = fromEvent(v, 'timeupdate').pipe(map(a => v.currentTime));
let lastIndex = 0,
    lastTime = 0;
const danmaku$ = new Observable(subscriber => {
    time$.subscribe(time => {
        const index = search(data, time);
        if (Math.abs(time - lastTime) > 1) {
            // user drag the progress bar
            subscriber.next(data[index]);
        } else {
            for (let i = lastIndex; i < index; i++) {
                subscriber.next(data[i]);
            }
        }
        lastIndex = index;
        lastTime = time;
    });
});

danmaku$.subscribe(d => {
    console.log(d.time, d.content);
});
```